# Php: how to get video urls in my vimeo account

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I have a vimeo api keys and i uploaded videos this url https://vimeo.com and get my all videos link from this link https://vimeo.com/home/myvideos. Now i got response for all my video links details.

```
<?php
    $urls   = array();
    $videos = array();
    // vimeo test
    $urls[] = 'https://vimeo.com/243625359';
    $urls[] = 'https://vimeo.com/243438242';

    foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $videos[] = getVideoDetails($url);
    }
    function getVideoDetails($url)
    {
    $host = explode('.', str_replace('www.', '', strtolower(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST))));
    $host = isset($host[0]) ? $host[0] : $host;
    switch ($host) {
    case 'vimeo':
    $video_id = substr(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), 1);
    $hash = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/{$video_id}.json"));
    // header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    // print_r($hash);
    // exit;
    return array(
    'provider'          => 'Vimeo',
    'title'             => $hash[0]->title,
    'description'       => str_replace(array("<br>", "<br/>", "<br />"), NULL, $hash[0]->description),
    'description_nl2br' => str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\r\n", "\n\r"), NULL, $hash[0]->description),
    'thumbnail'         => $hash[0]->thumbnail_large,
    'video'             => "https://vimeo.com/" . $hash[0]->id,
    'embed_video'       => "https://player.vimeo.com/video/" . $hash[0]->id,
    );
    break;

    }
    }
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    print_r($videos);
```

Response:

```
 Array
   (
   [0] => Array
    (
        [provider] => Vimeo
        [title] => SampleVideo_1280x720_10mb
        [description] => Vimeo was born in 2004, created by a group of 
        filmmakers who wanted an easy and beautiful way to share videos with 
        their friends. Word started to spread, and an insanely supportive 
        community of creators began to blossom. Now Vimeo is home to more 
        than:
        [description_nl2br] => Vimeo was born in 2004, created by a group of 
             filmmakers who wanted an easy and beautiful way to share videos 
         with their friends. Word started to spread, and an insanely 
        supportive community of creators began to blossom. Now Vimeo is home 
         to more than:
        [thumbnail] => http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/667808655_640.jpg
        [video] => https://vimeo.com/243625359
        [embed_video] => https://player.vimeo.com/video/243625359
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [provider] => Vimeo
        [title] => SampleVideo_1280x720_5mb
        [description] => We spend our days building a product we love for a growing community of millions. And eating lots of free snacks.
        [description_nl2br] => We spend our days building a product we love for a growing community of millions. And eating lots of free snacks.
        [thumbnail] => http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/667575091_640.jpg
        [video] => https://vimeo.com/243438242
        [embed_video] => https://player.vimeo.com/video/243438242
    )
```

)

It's good. I applied my video links manually, but correct way to apply my video links dynamic. I want to get my vimeo video urls in based api keys.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're using the old Simple API (with this url format: `http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/{$video_id}.json`) which is no longer supported by Vimeo.

That said, if your videos are embeddable, you'll likely be better off using oEmbed to get the specified metadata (provider, title, description, thumbnail, video). Vimeo's oEmbed documentation is found here: https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed

Regarding the `video` and `embed_video` values you're generating, it's best practice to get the video link and embed code exactly from the API. Because you're generating these values on your own, any changes we make to the URL structure may break your links. For example, unlisted videos have an additional hash after the numerical video_id that your code does not account for.

I hope this information helps!